# NPM - package.json#engines | How to specify Python?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, package.json

I need to specify a `python` version on my `package.json`.

Can I simple do:
`{ engines: { "python": "2.7.11" } }` ?

Answer (score 1):

As of NPM 7.x (same is valid for legacy NPM 6.x), the only valid entries for `"engines"` field in `package.json`, are the `"node"` version, and the `"npm"` version.
Furthermore, this is not a *hard* constraint unless you use `"engine-strict"` as well, as stated by the NPM [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#engines):

> Unless the user has set the `engine-strict` config flag, this field is advisory only and will only produce warnings when your package is installed as a dependency.

Your requirement, expecting a specific `python` version, is more related to an environment requirement than to your Node/NPM environment.

You can achieve this by implementing a `"postinstall"` NPM script that can result an error if the desired version is not found:

```json
{ 
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "node ./check-python.js"
  }
}
```

This script will be executed by NPM automatically after `npm install`. You could also use "preinstall" instead.
Consider using it on your "build" or "prebuild" scripts as well, based on your requirements. See more details on NPM pre- and post- scripts in the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scripts#pre--post-scripts).

Then, your `check-python.js` script could be something like:

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');

const EXPECTED_PYTHON_VERSION = "2.7.11";

exec('python -c "import platform; print(platform.python_version())"',
     function(err, stdout, stderr) {
  const currentPythonVersion = stdout.toString();
  if(currentPythonVersion !== EXPECTED_PYTHON_VERSION) { 
    throw new Error(`Expected Python version '${EXPECTED_PYTHON_VERSION}' but found '${currentPythonVersion}'. Please fix your Python installation.`);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting `"engines": { "python": "2.7.11" }` won't cause any issues (as far as I am aware) in your package.json, but it won't actually do anything either.

Determining an appropriate way to do this depends on particulars of your project. If it's about Python code you've written, you can check the version within the Python script itself. If it's about a build step in `package.json`, you can perhaps test as part of the build step.